# Perform subqueries for each day in range

Tags: sql, django, django-queryset

I building a 'airbnb clone' app on Django. The app has a flexible price system. Each landlord-user can save arbitrary number of prices which differ by priority and date range.
Here is how it looks like (most of the fields skipped for the sake of simplicity):

```
class PriceBlock(models.Model):
    price = models.DecimalField()
    priority = models.CharField(choices=PRIORITY_CHOICES)
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()

class Flat(models.Model):
    prices = models.ManyToManyField(PriceBlock, related_name='flats')
```

For example User created 3 `PriceBlock` instances with date values in some random month.
[image]

`p1` - has priority 1, price 100$ and dates from 1 to 3
`p2` - has priority 2, price 200$ and dates from 2 to 5
`p3` - has priority 3, price 300$ and dates from 4 to 6
To calculate price for flat from 1 to 6 days on this month we need to calculate price of PriceBlock with higher priority on each day.
The problem is - I need calculate price for each flat in the ListView of all flats.
Here's how I do it:

```
class FlatQueryset(models.QuerySet):
    ...
    def with_block_full_price(self, start, end):
        days = get_days(start, end) # function returns list of days nums
        prices = {}

        for num, day in enumerate(days):
            prices[f'price_{num}'] = Subquery(
                PriceBlock.objects.filter(flats=OuterRef('pk'))
                    .filter(start_date__lte=day, end_date__gte=day)
                    .order_by('-priority')
                    .values('price')[:1],
                output_field=models.IntegerField(null=True))
        return self.annotate(**prices).annotate(full_sum=sum([F(key) for key in prices.keys()]))
```

I create subqueries in loop, each subquery returns `price` value most prioritize PriceBlock or `null`, in case of `null` I don't show the `Flat`. Then I add all `price` values to `full_sum` value.

As far as I know I can't do queries like this in raw SQL without repeating all subqueries for each date. 
I also have a task on calculating rating of each flat and I did it in similar way.
I curios maybe there is much better solution on task like this, because my solution looks messy.

Comment: You forgot a related model in `prices` field.

Comment: @hynekcer thanks, fix it

Comment: Your solution is the best possible if you need all columns "price_..." for all individual days. (and you don't want to use undocumented internal data structures of Django queries) A simpler normal solution is possible if you need only results aggregated by the date range like `full_sum` or min/max of something and naturally that a price exists for all required days. (It is useful to select some best result and enumerate individual values only for them.)

Comment: @hynekcer thanks, now I'm not worried now about my solution